# Django Error - AttributeError: 'CourseOverview' object has no attribute 'start_datetime_text'

Tags: python, django, mako, edx

I have been trying to get this theme working for Open edX (based on Django) and I am getting this error in supervisor logs -

```
AttributeError: 'CourseOverview' object has no attribute 'start_datetime_text'
```

The whole error is this -

```
May 14 11:43:36 ip-172-26-15-154 [service_variant=lms][django.request][env:sandbox] ERROR [ip-172-26-15-154  20450] [base.py:256] - Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 132, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 145, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 110, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/common/djangoapps/util/cache.py", line 78, in wrapper
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/lms/djangoapps/branding/views.py", line 94, in index
    return student.views.index(request, user=request.user)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/common/djangoapps/student/views.py", line 221, in index
    return render_to_response('index.html', context)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/common/djangoapps/edxmako/shortcuts.py", line 198, in render_to_response
    return HttpResponse(render_to_string(template_name, dictionary, context_instance, namespace, request), **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/common/djangoapps/edxmako/shortcuts.py", line 188, in render_to_string
    return template.render_unicode(**context_dictionary)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mako/template.py", line 454, in render_unicode
    as_unicode=True)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mako/runtime.py", line 829, in _render
    **_kwargs_for_callable(callable_, data))
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mako/runtime.py", line 864, in _render_context
    _exec_template(inherit, lclcontext, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mako/runtime.py", line 890, in _exec_template
    callable_(context, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/mako_lms/c11f9c5f254718c770fcf021e95ac093/main.html.py", line 286, in render_body
    __M_writer(filters.decode.utf8(self.body()))
  File "/tmp/mako_lms/c11f9c5f254718c770fcf021e95ac093/marvel-theme-eucalyptus/lms/templates/index.html.py", line 54, in render_body
    runtime._include_file(context, (courses_list), _template_uri)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mako/runtime.py", line 752, in _include_file
    callable_(ctx, **_kwargs_for_include(callable_, context._data, **kwargs))
  File "/tmp/mako_lms/c11f9c5f254718c770fcf021e95ac093/marvel-theme-eucalyptus/lms/templates/courses_list.html.py", line 44, in render_body
    runtime._include_file(context, u'course.html', _template_uri, course=course)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mako/runtime.py", line 752, in _include_file
    callable_(ctx, **_kwargs_for_include(callable_, context._data, **kwargs))
  File "/tmp/mako_lms/c11f9c5f254718c770fcf021e95ac093/marvel-theme-eucalyptus/lms/templates/course.html.py", line 60, in render_body
    __M_writer(filters.html_escape(filters.decode.utf8(course.start_datetime_text())))
AttributeError: 'CourseOverview' object has no attribute 'start_datetime_text'
```

The file in question (the one that is giving the error - course.html.py) is here
https://pastebin.com/0S79hhDa

Comment: Have you got database migrations that need to be run? Those often cause errors similar to this.

Comment: change your file name to course.py

Comment: @Exprator Are you sure about that? I think all the files in the directory are named as [*].html.py and the others are working fine

Answer (score 0):

The `start_datetime_text` method was [removed](https://github.com/edx/edx-platform/commit/b0bf19a741bd858aa86e8b70f152edc22e0a3370#diff-d4028545aab3f00df980fa9ba8aab1b8) on november 30, 2016.

You should be using `course.advertised_start`. You can see the [current version](https://github.com/edx/edx-platform/blob/bd87b218ce6c82102b63801e608bd8e69c15bff9/lms/templates/course.html) of the course.html template